# How to create Kentico media library file using file stream

Tags: c#, kentico, kentico-api

I'm trying to use Kentico API (Kentico.Libraries 12.0.54) in a console app to create a media library file.

The [example on docs site](https://docs.kentico.com/api9/content-management/media-libraries#Medialibraries-Creatingamedialibraryfile) shows how to do this using a file on the file system. But in our case the file source will be a `MemoryStream`.

Is that possible using the out-of-the-box API or do I need to save the `MemoryStream` to a temp file on the file system before pushing it to Kentico CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to check out this similar question:

[Kentico - Pass MemoryStream file to MediaFileInfo API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350659/kentico-pass-memorystream-file-to-mediafileinfo-api)

But it doesn't look like you can pass the `MemoryStream` directly to create the file.

Comment: I will just add to this so no new answer. Media library file as MediaFileInfo is a meta data wrapper with information regarding media file and its actual path as well as extansion and fun things like that. But post Zach links is correct and you just need to use common .NET api or CMS.IO to save stream to file and create a mediaFileInfo on top of that. Without this mediaFileInfo, UI will be able to locate file on hard drive, but Kentico on its own will not know much about the file and will display warning in the UI.

Comment: @MichalSamuhel this is a console app. no UI involved.